# Assign Tuple that inside Task

Tags: c#, vb.net, tuples, task

I have function in C# that return
`Task<Tuple<bool, string, Passport>>` 
the signature is: 
`public async Task<Tuple<bool, string, Passport>> MyFunc(Stream FileData, string fileName)`

I need to call this function inside vb function, so i declare the return value like this: 
`Dim result As Task(Of Tuple(Of Boolean, String, Passport))` 
I dont find the syntax how to assign value like this (Task that have Tuple inside)

[image]

**How i can initialize this value?**

Comment: Show the actual code, this is likely easily solved

Comment: your method is async have awaited your call to that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I solve it:

1. I added the work `Async` in the vb function signature
2. Initialize the tuple like this:
   `Dim result As Tuple(Of Boolean, String, Passport) = New Tuple(Of Boolean, String, Passport)(False, "", New Passport)`
3. I added `Await` when I call to the C# function

Comment: Why would you need to create a `Tuple` yourself? You said that you want to call the method so the `Tuple` is being created inside the method and returned to you.

Comment: I must initialize the tuple, if I don't do this I get a warning error: "Variable 'result' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime"

Answer (score 1):

You would normally call a method with that signature like this:

```vb
Dim result = Await MyFunc(someStream, someString)
```

The `result` variable will be type `Tuple(Of Boolean, Stri8ng, Passport)`. The method returns the `Task` and the `Await` operator awaits the completion of that `Task` and returns its result.